# indexOn for nested data Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't get the structure for my rules correct so that I can access nested data.
Here is my raw json:

```
{
  "Field1" : "test",
  "Field2" : "tests"
},
"client": {
    "client_field": "Test!"
 }
```

I am trying to do my rules so that I can access the main fields `field1` `field2` but also the nested `client_field`

Here are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1635274993000",  // 2021-10-26
    ".write": "now < 1635274993000",  // 2021-10-26
      "call": {
            ".indexOn":["field1", "field2", "client"]
      },
  }
}
```

I have tried a few different ways but can't seem to get the syntax, and get an `Error saving rules` from Firebase.

edit:

My database is structured like so:

```
database
calls
  - "Field1", "Field2"
     - clients
       - "client field"
```

So calls is the top level, in each call there is `field1`, `field2` and `client` and client has its nested field `client field`

I want to be able to `indexOn` client field, so that I can get data where `client field` is a specific value.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your dabase or a description how it is structured?

Comment: @TarikHuber Hi I have updated my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To index a nested field, you can specify its entire path in the index statement. So:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1635274993000",  // 2021-10-26
    ".write": "now < 1635274993000",  // 2021-10-26
      "call": {
        ".indexOn":["field1", "field2", "client/client_field"]
      },
  }
}
```

With this, you can now order/filter on this nested field by doing `callRef.orderByChild("client/client_field")`.

Comment: Hi, I get a KeyError using this. It may be worth noting I am using Pyrebase, so I did: `db.child("calls").order_by_child('client/id').equal_to(1).get()`

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code, rules, and the exact/complete error message you get?